# How to read the value of -2.0138e-01

Tags: notation

Is -2.0138e-01  equal to -0.20138 (or) -0.00138 (or) 0.20138 (or) 0.00138.

Not sure how to read the -ve numbers and positive numbers.

This website(http://www.easysurf.cc/scintd.htm) shows 0.00138 for -2.0138e-01.

Not quite sure, if that's right

Comment: The scientific notation calculator you link to was not written to accept negative answers . This it leaves off the -2. This is why you are getting the weird result.

Comment: @KitterCatter: Ahh, interesting.  I couldn't try it out from work.

Answer (score 2):

I'd interpret that as $-0.20138$.  I don't quite understand why the $2$ or the negative sign should be ignored.

\begin{align}
-2.0138E-01 & = -2.0138 \times 10^{-1} \\
            & = -2.0138 \times 0.1 \\
            & = -0.20138
\end{align}

Comment: This is computer output notation.  From back in the Olden Days when computers had only a limited character set.  In particular, no exponents.  Is there any reason (besides inertia) to use it any more?

Comment: @GEdgar: Text consoles still don't have a full superscript set.  I wouldn't say that's a terribly common use case (although it applies to me), but it's *a* reason.

Comment: @GEdgar,  This is what the output from regression model in R says 'distance_value             -2.0138e-01'. figuring out on how to read the notation and what it stands for.

Comment: Those oldie computer languages more than 20 years old, like R, may still use this notation.